# Pagination on search query not formatting properly WP

Tags: wordpress, search, pagination

I have in my pagination code below I have seemed to figured out how to omit the /page/1/ from the first link of my pagination like this 'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%', on news posts and archive pages etc. But now on search queries http://url.com/?s=query the next pagination ends up like this ?s=querypage2 instead of /page/2/?s=query which was how it was previously.

How to get it on search queries it moves page/2/ before the query? Thanks

```
function vb_pagination( $query=null ) {
  global $wp_query;
  $query = $query ? $query : $wp_query;
  $big = 999999999;
   $paginate = paginate_links( array(
    //'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'type' => 'array',
    'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),   
     )
  );
  if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) :
  ?>
  <nav>
  <ul class="pagination">
  <?php
  foreach ( $paginate as $page ){
      echo '<li>' . $page . '</li>';
   }
  ?>
  </ul>
  </nav>
  <?php
     endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to have worked out the answer by adding a conditional `base`

```
function vb_pagination( $query=null ) {
  global $wp_query;
  $query = $query ? $query : $wp_query;
  $big = 999999999;
  $searchQ = str_replace( home_url(), '', '%_%' . get_pagenum_link(1));  
  $postsPagesBase = get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%';
  if(!is_search()){
  $paginate = paginate_links( array(
  'base' => $postsPagesBase,
  'type' => 'array',
  'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
  'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
  'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
  'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),   
   )
 );
} else {
$paginate = paginate_links( array(
  'base' => $searchQ,
  'format' => '/page/%#%',
  'type' => 'array',
  'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
  'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
  'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
  'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),   
  )
);
}
if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) :
  ?>
  <nav>
  <ul class="pagination">
  <?php
  foreach ( $paginate as $page ){
      echo '<li>' . $page . '</li>';
   }
  ?>
  </ul>
  </nav>
  <?php
     endif;
}
```